# $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function with bounded derivative, then is $\int_0^1 f'(x)=f(1)-f(0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f'(x)|$ is finite. Then since $f'(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$, so $f'(x)$ is measurable and also the Lebesgue integral $\int_0^1|f'(x)|dx$ is finite, thus $f' \in L^1([0,1])$.

My question is, is it true that $\int_0^1 f'(x)=f(1)-f(0)$ ?

Note that fundamental theorem of calculus does not apply here since $f'(x)$ is not continuous (not even known to be Riemann integrable)

Comment: Use Barrow rule

Comment: @TitoEliatron: what is that ?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary
In Spanish it is known as Barrow's Rule.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: see my question again

Comment: Second part of FTC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part

Also holds for Integrable functions

Comment: @TitoEliatron: again ... we do not know that $f'$ is Riemann integrable ... we only know it is Lebesgue integrable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lebesgue integrability is enough. You need the following version of FTC:

> Let ${[a,b]}$ be a compact interval of positive length, let ${F: [a,b] \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ be a differentiable function, such that ${F'}$ is absolutely integrable. Then the Lebesgue integral ${\int_{[a,b]} F'(x)\ dx}$ of ${F'}$ is equal to ${F(b) - F(a)}$.

This is a standard result in real analysis. See for instance [this excellent set](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/16/245a-notes-5-differentiation-theorems/) of lecture notes by Terry Tao.

Comment: thanks a lot ... do you know of any text book reference of this ?

Comment: You are welcome. One immediate textbook I know is Tao's one: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/an-introduction-to-measure-theory/